# how to find your github repository name

Tags: git, github

My problem is two fold. I have my node js directory I never should have uploaded to my repository. I have since then added it to get ignore but it is still in my repository. Because of some long file names "node_modules" has, I am unable to clone my repository through github (it errors out). I just need to wipe the entire directory.  I am fine with the nuclear option too, but I can't get in to do it.

So I opened up git gui (I have no issue using the git console, I would have the same problem though) but it asks me to open an existing repository. I put in the github clone URL of the particular repository with and without the https and it just says that is what I typed in is not a Git repository.

If it helps any my git repository is:
https://github.com/shellwe/Great-Plains-Landscaping-WP

Comment: Okay, I have discovered that the git gui only works with local repositories. I was able to get the directory cloned with git and opened up with git gui but that's not any clearer, but now that I have a local repository with all the files, how would select the repository I opened, go nuclear on node_modules, and then commit my changes?

Comment: So your problem is that you have a node_modules directory that you wish to remove from github? When you push you sync up the changes in your local repository and your remote repository. If you have managed to locally clone the repository, delete the offending folder, commit the changes, and push to make your changes reflect to github. Git Gui works with remote repositories but not directly (as each repository is independent)

Comment: gsp8181, thank you for your response! That was one of my considerations, I wish that when you add a directory to gitignore then it would see that it has been removed from git and take it out of the current repository... I was surprised to see it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

The nuclear option is fine if you want to reupload it

Do a `git init` in a blank folder, or create a new repository in the GUI (to a blank folder)

Add the remote end point to https://github.com/shellwe/Great-Plains-Landscaping-WP.git

Commit something to the repository (such as a new LICENCE file)

Push with `git push -f origin master`, or if you want to use the git GUI, press push and check force overwrite existing branch. This will delete everything in the repository and start you off with just a licence file.

Answer (score 0):

Your repository can be cloned just fine in command-line on Linux. It may have filenames issues on Windows, but if you have access to a non-Windows machine, you should do your cleaning there and push the result.

clone works with git-gui too, but you need to select "clone existing repository". "Open an existing repository" is for local repositories (i.e. after you did the clone).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was able to clone it with git, but the github application was having an issue. I also had issues with winzip if I downloaded the zip and tried to take them out, it told me the file names were too long. Kind of interesting the command line can download them the github application can't.